# Shortcut to go to a function in Netbeans

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, netbeans-8

In Eclipse, I can go to a function by toggling `Ctrl + Mouse Left Click`. It doesn't seem to work in Netbeans. Is there an alternative to do so? It would save me a lot of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Netbeans <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Left Click</kbd> should work. (For me it's working)

or place the cursor on method(function) call and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> **or** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> so this will take you to the method definition(method body).

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: It actually works in Netbean too for other projects. It just didnt work for my current project for some weird reason. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Deleting the cache can sometimes fix that, @RedBottle.